# Python Neo4j interactions without starting the server

Tags: java, python, neo4j

I've been using py2neo to interact with Neo4j server and create and query my database. I've recently come to know that in Java, Neo4j provides a default class named ExecutionEngine, using which you can do all your Neo4j trasactions without actually starting the Neo4j server! I wanted to know whether such a thing exists for python too? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is not.

Actually there is no in Java as well.

To be completely clear: The ExecutionEngine always uses a Neo4j database. This can be a Neo4j Server, when running the code as part of a Neo4j server-plugin or you can use an embedded database. In both ways, there is a Neo4j database running.

The normal way of working with Python is through the REST api, so you need to have the server running.

There is a driver called python-embedded that is using JPype to bind to the Java code, this is not updated to the last version of Neo4j though, and I don't know how stable it is.
http://docs.neo4j.org/drivers/python-embedded/snapshot/

Comment: +1 As with most drivers, py2neo uses the REST interface which requires the server to be running. The python-embedded project is not current and shouldn't be considered as an option.